# problema barra de salud en swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, spritekit

Estoy aprendiendo swift 4 y bueno haciendo un juego para aprender con algunos tutoriales y agregando algunas cosas yo 
pude crear la barra de salud cada enemigo tiene una pero cuando el enemigo colisiona con el player la barra disminuye toda su salud cuando deberia disminuir el ataque del player

Les dejo el codigo para que vean si me pueden ayudar

`introducir el código aquí`

```
func initZombie(){

      let enemy = Enemigo(imageNamed: "zombie1")

        var textures:[SKTexture] = []
        for i in 1...2 {
            textures.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "zombie\(i)"))

        }
        let anima:SKAction = SKAction.animate(with: textures, timePerFrame: 15.0)
        enemy.run(SKAction.group([
            SKAction.repeatForever(anima),
            SKAction.speed(to: 60.0, duration: 0)


            ]),withKey: "animation")





    enemy.healt = 300
    enemy.exp = 100


    enemy.barraEnemy = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.green, size: enemy.barravidaSizeE)
    enemy.barraEnemyBack = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.red, size: CGSize(width: enemy.barravidaSizeE.width + 300, height:  enemy.barravidaSizeE.height + 30))



   enemy.barraEnemy.position = CGPoint(x: enemy.position.x , y: enemy.position.y - 150)
    enemy.barraEnemy.zPosition = 101
   enemy.barraEnemy.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0 , y: 0.5)
    enemy.addChild(enemy.barraEnemy)

    enemy.barraEnemyBack.position = CGPoint(x: enemy.position.x , y: enemy.position.y - 150)
    enemy.barraEnemyBack.zPosition = 100
    enemy.barraEnemyBack.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    enemy.addChild(enemy.barraEnemyBack)

    enemy.barraEnemy.size = CGSize(width: enemy.barravidaSizeE.width + CGFloat(enemy.healt) , height: enemy.barravidaSizeE.height + 30)

    enemy.zPosition = 100
        //enemy.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
    enemy.position = CGPoint(x:random(min: -1100 , max: 1100), y: random(min: -400 , max: 400))
    enemy.enemyName = "zombie"
    enemy.setScale(0.4)

        addChild(enemy)

        enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody.init(rectangleOf: enemy.size)
        enemy.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
        enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 3
        enemy.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 1
        enemy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 1
        enemy.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true      

}



func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody:SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody:SKPhysicsBody


    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    }else{
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA

    }
    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == 1 && secondBody.categoryBitMask == 2 {
        life += 100

        secondBody.node?.removeFromParent()

    }
        if firstBody.categoryBitMask == 1 && secondBody.categoryBitMask == 3  {
            score += 1



            if let myEnemy = secondBody.node as? Enemigo {

                myEnemy.healt -= CGFloat(playerAtack)

                life -= zombieAtack

                myEnemy.barraEnemy.size = CGSize(width: myEnemy.barravidaSizeE.width + myEnemy.healt, height: myEnemy.barravidaSizeE.height)



                print(myEnemy.healt)
                if myEnemy.healt <= 0 {
                    playerAtack += 10
                    life += 100
                    spawnItem(point: secondBody.node!.position)
                    secondBody.node?.removeFromParent()


                 }
        }
  }




 class Enemigo : SKSpriteNode  {
    var healt : CGFloat = 300
    var enemyName : String = ""
    var exp : Int = 0
    var enemyPosition = CGPoint()
    var barravidaSizeE = CGSize()
    var barraEnemy = SKSpriteNode()
    var barraEnemyBack = SKSpriteNode()



}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes Manuel, te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas mas del funcionamiento del sitio y ademas obtienes tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges). Por otra parte revisa [ask] y también revisa [mcve] para que tu código sea mas legible.

Comment: puedes poner la clase del player para ver cuanto es el valor de "playerAtack" ?

Answer (score 0):

El problema a nivel lógico, es que la colisión ocurre demasiadas veces en un corto tiempo, efectivamente debe estar reduciendo lo que corresponde pero muchas veces en poco tiempo.

Como posibles ideas para solucionarlo:

1. Hacer que el player cambie el bitMask por un tiempo para que no pueda recibir colisiones.
2. Alejar al enemigo o el player para que no estén en colisión una vez dañado.
3. El player podría bajar una cantidad máxima por segundo su HP.

Debes buscar la forma que las multiples colisiones no afecten la mecánica de tu juego.